# How to get the WPF column binding field from DataGridColumnHeader style

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, datagridtextcolumn, datagridcolumnheader

I am doing custom sorting for WPF datagrid (as I use pagination so I can not use default sorting), how can I get name of the field that column binding to? Below is my current code inside `DataGrid.Resources`

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
    </Style>
```

I try to get the `Column` but it return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I give the style a key

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SortableColumnHeader" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Column.Binding.Path.Path, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

and apply it in column's HeaderStyle and it worked

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Column Name" MinWidth="150" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SortableColumnHeader}"/>
```